# Blessed way to extend Conda

Tags: anaconda, conda

I'm looking to capture additional information about a user's environment and would prefer not to create a new file format to track. Additionally, I'll be interacting with the conda.yaml file, so, given how widely used conda is, I was hoping there'd be a standard way of extending the file without causing any issue to anyone not using these tools.

Items that I am interested in tracking:

- SHA of a given commit
- Driver version the environment ran in (e.g. CUDA)
- System information (e.g.Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)
- Etc.

Is there a standard way to interact with the conda.yaml file and extend it with my custom metadata? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conda specifically has an [extra section](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#extra-section) that you should use for this.

```
extra:
  sha: hash
  driver: CUDA
  system: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
```